# Is there any possibile issue in having Anaconda Python 3.6 as default Python version in macOS?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I've just installed Anaconda on my macOS machine and it has changed my PATH so that now Python 3.6 is the default version (i.e. the Python 3.6 interpreter opens when I type python in the Terminal). I'm fine with this since this is the version I usually use, but I was wondering if there is the possibility of this messing up with the system functionalities relying on having 2.7 as default. I suppose that there will no problems since 2.7 is still in `/usr/bin`, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: I have been using Anaconda 3 (3.4, then 3.5, now 3.6) for several years on my MacBook, and have had no issues whatsoever. Anecdote != data, but...

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Anaconda Python.

I had a problem with the default Python installed on my Mac OSX 10.11 at one point, because of the numpy package.

It was a problem for me when I tried to run a script in Anaconda Python which relies on a numpy version higher the Mac default version and I wasn't able to get it working using `conda install`, `pip install`, or by changing the PATH/PYTHONPATH.

I was able to install the package but Anaconda Python would not recognize the new version.

I ended up removing the entire numpy that came with the Mac. But I do not think this would be a problem in the other way (i.e., using mostly the Mac python but occasionally install other packages for Anaconda Python) because the default Python does not look at the Ancondoa package directory.